# Stop the closing of modal popup when user clicks the background area

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using this [Angular modal popup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).Could you tell me how to stop the closing of modal popup when user clicks the background area ? I mean without using the `Close` or `Cancel` button of the popup.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e0SlTFjGdX1d1rX8bWXZ?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the option when invoking the modal to open:

```
backdrop: 'static'
```